# IP Forward at router

Tags: ip, router, redirect, forwarding

Is there any way to set a router to simply redirect all traffic to another wan IP address? For example, I have a static wan ip of xx.xxx.xxx.123 and I want to forward all traffic to xx.xxx.xxx.124

This has nothing to do with port forwarding. Basically, we are moving static ips and this scenario is similar to a temporary change of address scenario, where we want all mail to temporarily forward to another address for a couple days.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Short answer: Yes.</strike>

Longer answer: What kind of router are you using?  If you're using a Cisco router you may be able to use Policy Based Routing, [Cisco gives a few examples](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/ip-routed-protocols/47121-pbr-cmds-ce.html).

You can set up a static route in the routing table on a Cradlepoint MBR95, [Page 65 of the PDF Manual](https://cradlepoint.com/sites/default/files/productdocs/MBR95_Manual_3.6.3.pdf) gives screenshots and instructions.

Comment: Cradlepoint MBR95 or I have some apple routers.